# Difference between Boolean(x) and !!x

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using JavaScript, is there any difference between

```
Boolean(x)
```

and

```
!!x
```

?

Comment: They produce the same result of converting your value `x` into a boolean. However, one is certainly shorter and for that reason you'll see it used frequently when minifying your javascript.

Comment: **explicit** vs **implicit**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: Also from duplicated answer.. Here you go `Boolean(foo) === !!foo` but `new Boolean(foo) !== !!foo` .. JS :D

Answer (score 2):

They both have the same output, but you have to watch out for the Boolean object vs function. The Boolean constructor (using the new keyword) is not a primitive `true` or `false` value. Whereas the !! operator evaluates if an object is truthy/falsey.

Here's a quote from MDN:

> Any object of which the value is not undefined or null, including a
>   Boolean object whose value is false, evaluates to true when passed to
>   a conditional statement.

So the following evaluates to false:

`new Boolean(false) === false`

but the following evaluates to true:

`Boolean(false) === false`

Comment: `Boolean(false)` is not the Boolean constructor, it's the Boolean function. You're thinking of `new Boolean(false)`

Answer (score 1):

What's also an interesting difference between them is that you are able to explicitly pass `Boolean` as an callback inside `Array#filter` function, while if you would like to use `!!`, you'd would firstly have to set a callback function and then return it.

`.filter(Boolean)` **✓**

`.filter(!!)` **✕**

`.filter((x) => !!x)` **✓** (can be simplified, though - `.filter((x) => x)`)

Comment: because `filter` tests for truthiness, couldn't you do `.filter(x => x)` instead of `!!x`? I still like Boolean for readability, and didn't know you could do this!

Comment: @FredStark Oh yeah, that's true. Thanks for it. Edited.

Comment: Just noticed your screen name  everyone should aspire to be a kind user